# Why docker keeps dumping unnecessary files?

Tags: docker, fiware, fiware-orion

I am running dockerised fiware-orion on remote host. I know that I have nearly 200GB of storage allocated, but realised docker is consuming so much of disk space dumping unnecessary files.

So every few days I have to check to ensure I have some storage enough for orion to run fine. Whenever entity-query returns empty, I know that docker has completely comsumed storage 100%. So I have to clean disk and start services running again. On average, it happens once a week.

```
$df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1       197G  187G     0 100% /
devtmpfs        1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.4G   12K  1.4G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.4G  138M  1.3G  10% /run
tmpfs           1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/dm-16       10G   49M   10G   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/a0f3c5ab84aa06d5b2db00c4324dd6bf7141500ff4c83e23e9aba7c7268bcad4
tmpfs           285M     0  285M   0% /run/user/0
/dev/dm-3        10G  526M  9.5G   6% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/0ef509f0c144e458c0c2f9bdbf6941e11d292a032953d48fb316c90caa05f21a
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/71eea4f1af5b284059599eb07cc2aa2d73bdeccc9885952f2062763c81528d8f/mounts/shm
/dev/dm-4        10G   99M  9.9G   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/3e108b5c2f45bcfe8c5f7ad28e7f8510ee666d5b4cd728a4b899857750440f1b
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/7e9c401ec8993d7f24870692f84926bf39e4673ec4f23e1d9a7b7147cbfdf9b7/mounts/shm
/dev/dm-2        10G  266M  9.8G   3% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/4d1e151d4270c38e96103713ddc9a3fc00b4e9411ddd89e3791c319508f12449
shm              64M  8.0K   64M   1% /var/lib/docker/containers/b6138e616e81c3e731499fc14793786fe60f334c6281f8116e8029d1cf561b6a/mounts/shm
/dev/dm-5        10G  325M  9.7G   4% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/e1c6b5e20fed47cf38fb287ec424dac4a5c65c660b40de68fd604360e09082e4
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/634ca1304587c7ad37b763512e7feece81e197a1229e4176213a9b70bb2984d0/mounts/shm
/dev/dm-6        10G   10G   20K 100% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/38fc5fa4880f505e58067e90674e1c560378a75c9cc993dd6a673d1dd674fdff
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/3a10f4a0e3123f7877a10f933d0d18df86b85b16b449457505f59e83d3e22192/mounts/shm
/dev/dm-8        10G  803M  9.3G   8% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/456c4aa19f3ad57d3e7abc4a69e972371cfec2b67faeee4e548f18b2affe42f8
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/e8964627c7b008829d4745c46d0210fe97d54f36693085145184243e17adba91/mounts/shm
/dev/dm-7        10G  1.2G  8.9G  12% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/39e19f7dc51ed511d887932e13903129d1a3f13a6aee6c0e69c8e9e63dacfa6c
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/1c2e3b465890a5cd010ab73bfc7f73c992e9abb49043357dc4916adeb74c8bed/mounts/shm
/dev/dm-10       10G  146M  9.9G   2% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/5913150a306d91b81d12cd5f759aeb1cd6a192ca7dcaffbd8581d4e8735cc2d1
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/6414fa2c750fcb723c836772d112589a67dff7ee636aa8e03c78e288b5d77ae5/mounts/shm
/dev/dm-11       10G   49M   10G   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/2e557f90bc0dcc7e6f85a7536b2b480ae1bd61dcaf778f3fa3a0db5f93503fcf
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/e9857010411222e00b1c990fdd15d61aa03576e9fe4b7829c98e140a33572dc2/mounts/shm
/dev/dm-9        10G  276M  9.8G   3% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/a57a351c9bfd8a30db66a7666ab940690a4c7431b26e6771c8bd381097d179a4
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/dcab63511f6bbd121213ed1fd667547c0339f70568d64747b5c280185951c510/mounts/shm
```

Disk clean:

```
$docker volume ls -qf dangling=true | xargs docker volume rm 2>&1 | cat;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.
.
.
```

Disk space (after disk clean):

```
$df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1       197G   38G  150G  20% /
devtmpfs        1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.4G  137M  1.3G  10% /run
tmpfs           1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/dm-16       10G   49M   10G   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/a0f3c5ab84aa06d5b2db00c4324dd6bf7141500ff4c83e23e9aba7c7268bcad4
tmpfs           285M     0  285M   0% /run/user/0
/dev/dm-11       10G   49M   10G   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/2e557f90bc0dcc7e6f85a7536b2b480ae1bd61dcaf778f3fa3a0db5f93503fcf
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/e9857010411222e00b1c990fdd15d61aa03576e9fe4b7829c98e140a33572dc2/mounts/shm
```

Disk space(one hour later):

```
$df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1       197G   39G  149G  21% /
devtmpfs        1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.4G   12K  1.4G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.4G  138M  1.3G  10% /run
tmpfs           1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/dm-16       10G   49M   10G   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/a0f3c5ab84aa06d5b2db00c4324dd6bf7141500ff4c83e23e9aba7c7268bcad4
tmpfs           285M     0  285M   0% /run/user/0
/dev/dm-11       10G   49M   10G   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/2e557f90bc0dcc7e6f85a7536b2b480ae1bd61dcaf778f3fa3a0db5f93503fcf
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/e9857010411222e00b1c990fdd15d61aa03576e9fe4b7829c98e140a33572dc2/mounts/shm
/dev/dm-2        10G   99M  9.9G   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/735a5508654bfdb6c0752838c5ab65ff7bf1b82a7329ea20ee215651a5ae39e2
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/95dd176c4df52b02fc8b8a78ebdbab444a7be1213a2cfc54beee134f450bad23/mounts/shm
/dev/dm-4        10G  526M  9.5G   6% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/1a749000c102efd084e52034a44cec2e8524ccdb75bcb27972f2f05dcf083ea8
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/a8178e76fb4107f90fe1187698d58e362969515343b0adf7c428436fe9d482cb/mounts/shm
/dev/dm-1        10G  383M  9.7G   4% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/1dc589a616892704fd55587a7d558307db703155a4fd743219addc7b5a65d962
/dev/dm-3        10G  266M  9.8G   3% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/7a501e67c52c5d2dbd77fd29cc68946469c3a609c2fe356b7bba7fde82f148a1
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/495918e5611c7a416ef20401f5701e1570b94f540eb5d764c47c6a74f73a169f/mounts/shm
shm              64M  8.0K   64M   1% /var/lib/docker/containers/374f9bb469ec5fe42b7e7772a5d4c580aa36178f64efac8b3fba02f148b42de6/mounts/shm
/dev/dm-6        10G  502M  9.6G   5% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/b58cbb82569f79848c432dae10c8e549ac2e783e1ba065def8a033cf94a625c8
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/98dd55e27406e756b870361e0e25cc7cca4f57a9e95161aa8a3359a13a477e58/mounts/shm
/dev/dm-7        10G  325M  9.7G   4% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/cfcfd404d2fa0e0fc770d34e1b6b0cd27bbef84390bfad02368760c4da2abe87
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/a1bb4f9e726902446809a85d17553b93f773d8013e227faa0a254d90f1821359/mounts/shm
/dev/dm-9        10G  1.2G  8.9G  12% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/1529c11ac704d149b94723287a390dd38d9373c58ed5ed0b21d8d0585a0a7ac7
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/8594cfcef1fe0cf3fa75bac83ce5ef18ef096cad6debe0957384fc424f3edc03/mounts/shm
/dev/dm-5        10G  276M  9.8G   3% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/88b94454d368ae2066fde71dd0062252b09fb87c8e4a3c8fda351013ea7a7182
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/e1900109937266b65090c366c60a70581c0584474346083c8a9b971831b3edaf/mounts/shm
/dev/dm-10       10G  803M  9.3G   8% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/9a84f16db1fe54d4d0d6719ab1a48c6d88d53880c65345c010bf8fc4164166d6
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/10db801e75d33f20f07954848ad2c8c3a4213d59c0046469c8a773fb1e0f172a/mounts/shm
/dev/dm-8        10G  146M  9.9G   2% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/dd643159c8d53030e6f9bac07353fabb4d279015b7f565c2f05fd60b074109d1
shm              64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/47ac2d9eb4beeddc4908ceb2c415abf9311cd4eac8d40825049c7965fd8644e4/mounts/shm
```

Isn't there a way to avoid this issue? I know this is completely docker issue, but added fiware-orion tag so if anyone had similar experience.

**EDIT:**

```
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                              TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
fiware/wirecloud                        latest              57588c317927        3 months ago        1.06GB
grafana/grafana                         latest              ffd9c905f698        3 months ago        241MB
postgres                                10                  3e016ba4a307        3 months ago        230MB
memcached                               1                   b26493421cee        3 months ago        62.1MB
telefonicaiot/lightweightm2m-iotagent   latest              8788b0f0e1e7        3 months ago        243MB
fiware/orion                            latest              4f5e794be6d8        4 months ago        271MB
fiware/cygnus-ngsi                      latest              1ecc85e54361        4 months ago        806MB
nginx                                   latest              f09fe80eb0e7        4 months ago        109MB
mongo                                   3.6                 2d6f175a24cf        4 months ago        361MB
elasticsearch                           2.4                 5e9d896dc62c        9 months ago        479MB
jbergknoff/postgresql-client            latest              23850b2852a4        15 months ago       11.5MB
```

containers running:

```
$docker-compose ps
        Name                      Command                  State                                Ports
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
fiware-cygnus          /cygnus-entrypoint.sh            Up (healthy)   0.0.0.0:5050->5050/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5080->5080/tcp
fiware-elasticsearch   /docker-entrypoint.sh elas ...   Up             9200/tcp, 9300/tcp
fiware-grafana         /run.sh                          Up             0.0.0.0:53153->3000/tcp
fiware-iotagent        pm2-runtime bin/lwm2mAgent ...   Up (healthy)   0.0.0.0:4041->4041/tcp, 5684/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5684->5684/udp
fiware-memcached       docker-entrypoint.sh memca ...   Up             11211/tcp
fiware-mongo           docker-entrypoint.sh --bin ...   Up             0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp
fiware-nginx           nginx -g daemon off;             Up             0.0.0.0:53152->53152/tcp, 80/tcp
fiware-orion           /usr/bin/contextBroker -fg ...   Up (healthy)   0.0.0.0:1026->1026/tcp
fiware-postgres        docker-entrypoint.sh postgres    Up             0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp
fiware-wirecloud       /docker-entrypoint.sh            Up (healthy)   8000/tcp
```

docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.1"

services:

 mongo:
   image: mongo:3.6
   hostname: mongo
   container_name: fiware-mongo
   ports:
     - "27017:27017"
   networks:
     - default
   command: --bind_ip_all --smallfiles
 #  volumes:
  #  - mongo-db:/data

 orion:
   image: fiware/orion
   hostname: orion
   container_name: fiware-orion
   depends_on:
     - mongo
   networks:
     - default
   ports:
     - "1026:1026"
   expose:
     - "1026"
   command: -dbhost mongo -logLevel DEBUG
   healthcheck:
    test: curl --fail -s http://localhost:1026/version || exit 1

 lightweightm2m-iotagent:
    image: telefonicaiot/lightweightm2m-iotagent
    hostname: idas
    container_name: fiware-iotagent
    depends_on:
     - mongo
    networks:
     - default
    expose:
     - "4041"
     - "5684"
    ports:
     - "4041:4041"
     - "5684:5684/udp"
    environment:
     - "IOTA_CB_HOST=orion"
     - "IOTA_CB_PORT=1026"
     - "IOTA_NORTH_PORT=4041"
     - "IOTA_REGISTRY_TYPE=mongodb"
     - "IOTA_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG"
     - "IOTA_TIMESTAMP=true"
     - "IOTA_MONGO_HOST=mongo"
     - "IOTA_MONGO_PORT=27017"
     - "IOTA_MONGO_DB=lwm2miotagent"
     - "IOTA_HTTP_PORT=5684"
     - "IOTA_PROVIDER_URL=http://lightweightm2m-iotagent:4041"
     - "IOTA_AUTOCAST=true"
     - "IOTA_CB_NGSI_VERSION=v2"
    healthcheck:
     test: curl --fail -s http://localhost:4041/iot/about || exit 1
      comment

 cygnus:
    image: fiware/cygnus-ngsi:latest
    hostname: cygnus
    container_name: fiware-cygnus
    depends_on:
     - postgres
    networks:
     - default
    expose:
     - "5080"
    ports:
     - "5050:5050"
     - "5080:5080"
    environment:
     - "CYGNUS_POSTGRESQL_HOST=postgres"
     - "CYGNUS_POSTGRESQL_PORT=5432"
     - "CYGNUS_POSTGRESQL_USER=postgres"
     - "CYGNUS_POSTGRESQL_PASS=password"
     - "CYGNUS_LOG_LEVEL_=DEBUG"
     - "CYGNUS_SERVICE_PORT=5050"
     - "CYGNUS_API_PORT=5080"
     - "CYGNUS_POSTGRESQL_ENABLE_CACHE=true"
    healthcheck:
      test: curl --fail -s http://localhost:5080/v1/version || exit 1


 nginx:
    restart: always
    container_name: fiware-nginx
    image: nginx
    networks:
      - default
    ports:
      - "53152:53152"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
      - ./wirecloud-static:/var/www/static:ro
      - ./nginx_logs:/var/log/nginx
    depends_on:
      - wirecloud

 postgres:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:10
    hostname: postgres
    container_name: fiware-postgres
    expose:
      - "5432"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - default
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password"
      - "POSTGRES_USER=postgres"
      - "POSTGRES_DB=postgres"
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

 grafana:
    restart: always
    image: grafana/grafana
    container_name: fiware-grafana
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "53153:3000"
    environment:
      - plugins="crate-datasource,grafana-clock-panel,grafana-worldmap-panel"
    volumes:
      - ./grafana:/var/lib/grafana:rw
 elasticsearch:
    restart: always
    container_name: fiware-elasticsearch
    image: elasticsearch:2.4
    volumes:
      - ./elasticsearch-data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    command: elasticsearch  -Des.index.max_result_window=50000
 memcached:
    restart: always
    container_name: fiware-memcached
    image: memcached:1
    command: memcached -m 2048m
 wirecloud:
    restart: always
    image: fiware/wirecloud
    container_name: fiware-wirecloud
    depends_on:
        - postgres
        - elasticsearch
        - memcached
    environment:
        - DEBUG=False
        # - DEFAULT_THEME=wirecloud.defaulttheme
        - DB_HOST=postgres
        - DB_PASSWORD=password # Change this password!
        - FORWARDED_ALLOW_IPS=*
        - ELASTICSEARCH2_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200/
        - MEMCACHED_LOCATION=memcached:11211
        # Uncomment the following environment variables to enable IDM integration
        #- FIWARE_IDM_SERVER=${FIWARE_IDM_SERVER}
        #- SOCIAL_AUTH_FIWARE_KEY=${SOCIAL_AUTH_FIWARE_KEY}
        #- SOCIAL_AUTH_FIWARE_SECRET=${SOCIAL_AUTH_FIWARE_SECRET}
    volumes:
      - ./wirecloud-data:/opt/wirecloud_instance/data
      - ./wirecloud-static:/var/www/static
        #- ./settings.py:/opt/wirecloud_instance/wirecloud_instance/settings.py:ro
```

Comment: While you seek the solution, you could add the volume rm command and `docker system prune -f` to a crontab.

Comment: @Niloct can you please elaborate your suggestion.

Comment: Does this application startup new containers regularly? In that case cleaning up the volumes needs to be automated or you might be able to specify -rm but that’s rather risky.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem, or relevant fragments of the source of your application or the scripting that runs it?  Docker on its own doesn't spontaneously soak up disk space like this and it seems like _something_ is launching new containers.

Comment: We cannot tell you why this happens without knowing what images you are running and how. What are the volumes being created, by what containers, with what contents?

Comment: @BMitch question edited to show docker images/containers available.

Answer (score 1):

Use [crontab](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-schedule-routine-tasks-with-cron-and-anacron-on-a-vps) to schedule `docker system prune -f` to remove dangling volumes (i.e. volumes without associated running containers), images and containers from docker engine.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-remove-docker-images-containers-and-volumes

If you don't know the syntax of crontab, [this](https://crontab.guru/) may help.

**Edit**

```
*/5 * * * * docker system prune -f > /dev/null
```

This for instance runs the cleaning every 5 minutes on the server.

**UPDATE**

I found an interesting command that shows for a specific volume which containers are attached to it:

https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/31436#issuecomment-283190953

May be useful to identify the culprits for dangling volumes.